# Problems with regex

Tags: php, regex, tags, preg-replace, bbcode

A while ago, i've built the following regular expression:

```
~(?:<a.*?</a>|\[url.*?\[/url]|\[/?[^]]++]|</?[^>]++>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bcdkey\s*-\s*.*\b~is
```

This matches every kind of cdkey-xxx that's NOT inside of a bbcode or a html tag. That works fine so far.

However, i can't make it work properly when including bbcodes and html tags. I thought, removing the front part is enough, but i seem to be wrong:

```
~\bcdkey\s*-\s*.*\b~is
```

With this regex,

```
<a href="https://www.google.de/#q=cdkey-0192xdasas" class="externalURL">https://www.google.de/#q=cdkey-0192xdasas</a>
```

becomes

```
<a href="https://www.google.de/#q=***>
```

and

```
[url]https://www.google.de/#q=cdkey-0192xdasas[/url]
```

becomes

```
[url]https://www.google.de/#q=***]
```

while the expected results are

```
<a href="https://www.google.de/#q=***" class="externalURL">https://www.google.de/#q=***</a>
```

and

```
[url]https://www.google.de/#q=***[/url]
```

I have no idea, how to fix that.

---

So, what i try to achieve is to replace

```
[url]https://www.google.de/#q=cdkey-0192xdasas[/url]
[url=https://www.google.de/#q=cdkey-0192xdasas]Test[/url]
[img]https://www.google.de/#q=cdkey-0192xdasas[/img]
[url="https://www.google.de/#q=cdkey-0192xdasas"]Test 3[/url]
https://www.google.de/#q=cdkey-0192xdasas
    Another plaintext cdkey   -   bla
<a href="https://www.google.de/#q=cdkey-0192xdasas" class="externalURL">https://www.google.de/#q=cdkey-0192xdasas</a>
<a href='https://www.google.de/#q=cdkey-0192xdasas'>Le Google</a>
```

with

```
[url]https://www.google.de/#q=***[/url]
[url=https://www.google.de/#q=***]Test[/url]
[img]https://www.google.de/#q=***[/img]
[url="https://www.google.de/#q=***"]Test 3[/url]
Plaintext https://www.google.de/#q=***
    Another plaintext ***
<a href="https://www.google.de/#q=***" class="externalURL">https://www.google.de/#q=***</a>
<a href='https://www.google.de/#q=***'>Le Google</a>
```

Comment: Maybe you're using something that you have no idea what it does ? You're using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` which will tell the regex engine to fail. Basically, you need to remove it.

Comment: `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` is just used in the regex, which is working ;) It's not used in the problematic regex.

Comment: lolwut, you have 1 regex. So by definition it would be the "problematic" one, otherwise you wouldn't be asking.

Comment: I have two?! I guess, you didn't understand the introducion.

Comment: ok, let's make it clear. Do you want the `cdkey....` to be matched only inside the bb/a tags, or only outside or both ?

Comment: I want to replace every occurrence of cdkey-xxx (while xxx is random) in every case (bbcode, html tag AND standalone) by *** but without messing up the bb- and html-code-tags.

Comment: Can't you use something simple like this `\bcdkey\s*-\s*[a-z0-9]+\b` ? [demo](http://regex101.com/r/xN8wZ2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see with your regular expression is the `.*` part.

You're matching the **most amount possible** across your matches, and no need to use the `s` modifier.

If you know your *cdkey* will always be numbers and letters, you could do something like this.

```
$text = preg_replace('/cdkey\s*-\s*[a-z0-9]+/i', '***', $text);
```

See [working demo](https://eval.in/57438)

Comment: The problem is, that the cdkey can be everything (including asterisk, plus, bracket, etc...)

Comment: @user2368182 I've never seen such a key :o

Comment: If that's the case, you need to provide examples, because everything from your posted data is simply letters/numbers only as a cdkey...

Comment: The approach of this task is to build a censorship in PHP, which covers every (technically) possible case.

Comment: So you're stating a cdkey will look like `cdkey-011ab*[+ab0]**`? That is insane.

Comment: @user2368182 your task is then near-impossible given the following data `I haz the cdkey - trolololol and it haz numberz too 039443`. According to you `cdkey - trolololol and it haz numberz too 039443` is a valid cdkey.

Comment: You can't imagine, what people do to avoid a blacklist ;) So, stackoverflow could become st@ckoverflow for example. However, i guess, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word boundaries `\b` are not compatible with the syntax you have inside them. Specifically  <strike>the hyphen  and</strike> dot-star sequence  is not  going to match the same way It normally does.

Comment: That's exactly the utility of using `\b` it's to prevent some false matches. For example `\bman\b` will match `that's a man !` but it won't match `that's a policeman !`. [See demo](http://regex101.com/r/uM2lJ3)

Comment: @hamza edited that. Thanks for clarifying. Just the .* that isn't right there.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what might terminate the cdkey, something like this

```
 # \bcdkey\s*-\s*[^<>\[\]"'\s]*

 \b cdkey \s* - \s* [^<>\[\]"'\s]*
```